# mysql truncate rows of foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `drugs`, where i made the row values to.

```
id name 

1 Xenomine
2 Yeart
3 Zizan
```

But now, i have other values needs to be insert, Abaci, Bari (1000 of rows)

also i have appointments table, where i refer the drugs table

```
appointments

id time drug_id
```

So for, no datas has been made in (production) appointments table, even though i tried to truncate the drugs table, but could not.

how can i solve the issue

Comment: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`. Now try to truncate your tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you used the `truncate table` MySQL command, then it is no surprise that it does not work, as MySQL documentation on [truncate table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html) indicates:

> Truncate operations drop and re-create the table, which is much faster than deleting rows one by one, particularly for large tables.

If you have a foreign key pointing to a table, you cannot drop it, hence the error message. I do not recommend to turn foreign key checks off because it may leave your database in an inconsistent state. Use `delete from tablename` to get rid of all records in the parent table.

However, I do not even understand why you need to truncate your drugs table at all. Just insert the new drugs into the table and that's it.

Comment: Thanks man, you are right, just i thought that all datas can be neatly arranged  in ASC Order A, B, C etc.,